# Javascript form using regex not validating correctly

Tags: javascript, regex, forms

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bcon865y/5/ 
Sorry if this is a little vague..

Trying to create a javascript form which validates each field using a onblur function once a field gets tested as correct the background of the field will turn green.

The submit button has a function which if all fields are green it will submit the form, however all fields are green but the form is not passing validation. I have no idea why this is happening any insight would be greatly appreciated, Hope i explained it well enough.
Below is the function in question, view the js fiddle to get the full context.

```
function validate() {
    // Gets all the elements in the form with id="form1" 
    var elements = document.getElementById("form1").elements;
    // loops through all elements in the form 
    for (var i = 0, element; element = elements[i++];) {
        // Checks if the element in the form is either <input> or <select> && not green
        if ((element =='[object HTMLInputElement]' || element == '[object HTMLSelectElement]') && (element.style.backgroundColor !='rgb(204,255,204)')) {
            if (element.type!='color' && element.type!='submit') {
                alert("Please enter data for any fields that are not green");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // to test the color picker
    if (document.getElementById("color").value !='#000000') {
        alert("please select a colour from the colour picker");
        document.getElementById("The ID for your color picker goes here").focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Relying on the human readable string representation on an object is almost never a good idea. Consider changing `element =='[object HTMLInputElement]'` to `element instanceof HTMLInputElement`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're looking for a combination of the `pattern` field (on the input element) and the `:valid` & `:invalid` pseudo css selectors.

```css
input[type="text"]:valid {
  background: #BCED91;
}
input[type="text"]:invalid {
  background: #F08080;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text"
         id="name" 
         name="name" 
         required
         pattern="[01]+">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The example above colors any text fields red if their values doesn't match the regex `[01]+`, and green if they do match it.

You can read more about form validation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation